# Extending built-in types in Typescript JSDoc

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I would like to define one single function that would need to be available to every single value of every single type in the program (so, basically, on `Object.prototype`).

I know that this is generally considered evil and I don't care ;)

```js
// Just like this, but in JSDoc, WITHOUT having to create a d.ts file.
// I've tried so many different approaches from the internet and nothing seems to work.
declare global {
  interface Object {
    myFunc(): void;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid the d.ts file? It seems often JSDoc based projects have some d.ts files for more advanced typescript types. This file would not have to be part of any JS build or be distributed with the JS. It would just be there  for development. Not all TS syntax has JSDoc equivalents as far as I know

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir honestly, just OCD, I'd hate to have to create an extra file just for one function ever, on a project that doesn't even use typescript

Comment: Well.. you are using TypeScript, you're just using it thought JSDoc syntax :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir tru dat

Comment: Looking at the parse JSDoc code in TS I don't see any evidence of a tag that would allow global types to be defined https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/compiler/parser.ts#L8994